# Empire Earth 1 problem when load map

Tags: empire-earth

I have a problem with Empire Earth 1. From last week when I start the game, the intro video works fine as does the main menu.  However when the game starts to create the world (load map) it take some time, the game starts and all players including me are defeated! When I load a saved game it works fine and I can restart the game and start from the beginning.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

- OS - Windows 7 ultimate 32
- Nvidia Geforce GT 8600

Comment: Haven't played the game in like 10+ years, but any chance you somehow made everyone allied with everyone?